# How to swap rows in VSTO (excel)

Tags: c#, excel, sorting, vsto

I would like to sort an excel spreadsheet from VSTO in C#. But I want to use my own customer sorting technique and therefore can't use the Range.Sort method. I think if we can start with the ability to swap rows in a range that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think swapping rows would be way too slow for users but haven't tried it.
The [custom sorting in Excel](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/sorting-data/2/) is not suitable for you? I remember using it years ago in VBA (at that time probably Excel 2003)

If you are working with large amount of data (but also perfect for small) you can consider loading the range to an array, sort it via C# and then put it back to Excel.

```
System.Array dataArray = (System.Array)(range.Cells.Value2); //the value is boxed two-dimensional array
```

You will have to deal with formats then but I still assume that it will be much much much faster than manipulating with Excel range object